# Mocha test passes locally, but fails on Travis CI

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, travis-ci, chai

I am trying to add testing to the website I'm building. I'm using Mocha as my testing framework and Chai and expect as my assertion library. I made a simple test just to make sure things work and then I created a Gruntfile to run my tests. The test is a simple test that just verifies that `true === true` and it worked both locally and on Travis CI. Now, even though I haven't changed anything in the test, it only works locally, but fails on Travis CI. It was passing before and it still passes locally, so I'm not sure what to change.

My simple test code looks like this:

```js
'use strict';

var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;

describe('Test that tests run', function(done) {
  it('should run a test', function(done) {
    expect(true).to.eql(true);
    done();
  });
});
```

My Gruntfile looks like this:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-simple-mocha');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jscs');

  // initialize Grunt
  grunt.initConfig({
    // create jshint task
    jshint: {
      dev: {
        // tell jshint what check
        src: ['Gruntfile.js', 'server.js', 'js/**/*.js', 'models/**/*.js', 'routes/**/*.js', '!build/**', '!tests/client/bundle.js', '!tests/karma_tests/bundle.js', '!js/imageMapResizer.min.js', '!js/kickstart.js', '!js/form-validator.js'],
        options: {
          node: true,
          globals: {
            describe: true,
            it: true,
            before: true,
            after: true,
            beforeEach: true,
            afterEach: true,
            res: true
          }
        }
      },

      mocha: {
        // tell mocha where test files are
        src: ['tests/**/*.js', '!tests/client/bundle.js', '!tests/karma_tests/bundle.js'],
        options: {
          node: true,
          globals: {
            describe: true,
            it: true,
            before: true,
            after: true,
            beforeEach: true,
            afterEach: true,
            res: true,
            expect: true
          }
        }
      },
      // create jscs task
      jscs: {
        dev: {
          // tell jscs to test the same files as jshint
          src: ['<%= jshint.dev.src %>', '<%= jshint.mocha.src %>']
        }
      }
    },

    // create simplemocha task
    simplemocha: {
      dev: {
        src: ['tests/test_entry.js']
      }
    }
  });

  // register linting task
  grunt.registerTask('lint', ['jshint:dev', 'jshint:mocha' /*, 'jshint:jasmine'*/ ]);
  // register mocha test task
  grunt.registerTask('test', ['simplemocha:dev']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['test']);
};
```

And .travis.yml looks like this:

```js
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "4.1"
  - "4.0"
  - "0.12"
  - "0.11"
  - "0.10"
  - "0.8"
  - "0.6"
  - "iojs"
before_install:
  - npm install -g grunt-cli
script: grunt test
```

Let me know if you have questions or want to see more code. Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: Can you provide a link to your project?

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь you can see the full project on my [GitHub](https://github.com/mrbgit/event-site)

Comment: What's that `done` callback in the `describe` block?

Comment: @MarcoL the ```done()``` is the callback to mochajs to tell it that this describe block is completed. If I was testing for more than ```true === true``` I would add it before the ```done()``` callback. Search done() on [mochajs.org](https://mochajs.org/) to read more about how it works.

Comment: You're testing `sync` stuff in JS, so the use of the `done` callback in the `it` block is superflous. AFAIK the `done` callback is passed in the `after`, `afterEach`, `before`, `beforeEach` and `it` blocks, but not in the `describe` ones - and in you're code you're not calling it.

Comment: @MarcoL I removed the ```done()``` callback and ran the test and the test timed out with this error: ``` Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
      at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\Documents\GitHub\event-site\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:189:19)```

Comment: This line `describe('Test that tests run', function(done) {` should become `describe('Test that tests run', function() {` - without the `done` argument. The rest of the code can stay. After this change do you still have issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more digging with Travis CI I found there were 2 problems. The first was that node.js versions 0.6 and 0.8 were incompatible with many of my node packages. The other problem was 2 node packages I had included were not compatible with linux, which is the OS Travis CI uses to run tests. The packages were `node-sqlserver-unofficial` and `msnodesqlv8`.

I don't really need to work on node.js versions 0.6 or 0.8 and the I can work without the 2 node packages, so once I removed the the older node versions and the packages and my tests passed with flying colors.